# How to check in some project from some account on some machine which is not available on TFS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

One of my project let say my_project is checked out on a machine let say machine_A using account let say Account_mine.

I installed new OS and all application programs on machine_A by removing all hierarchies, now I am unable to check out my_project on any other machine, how can I check in from my machine_A? As now I have no Account_mine on machine_A?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you have checked out a project which has put an exclusive lock on it, and now you no longer have access to that account/machine?

If you launch a Visual Studio Command Prompt from your dev machine (using a project admin's account) then you can use **tf undo** to discard Account_mine's pending changes on Machine_A.

[Undo Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c72skhw4(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
c:\>tf undo /collection:http://fabrikam-3:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection
/workspace:FABRIKAM-1;JuliaI $/SiteApp/Main/SolutionA/Project1/program.cs
```

[TF Status](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s5ae285(v=vs.110).aspx) could be useful if you don't know what has been locked by that user